# How to grep 2 or 3 lines, one containing the text I want, and the others just below it?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

This is a snapshot of error log:

```
06:16:29,933 ERROR EmailRMManager$:45 - Exception In get Message
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown; reason: Attempt to use closed channel
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:195)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:222)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:208)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicGet(ChannelN.java:645)
```

I do the following command:

`cat foo.log | grep ERROR` to get an OP as:

`06:16:29,933 ERROR EmailRMManager$:45 - Exception In get Message`

What command should I execute to get the output as

```
06:16:29,933 ERROR EmailRMManager$:45 - Exception In get Message
    com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown; reason: Attempt to use closed channel
```

ie, also grep the line(s) after the pattern?

Comment: Is `com.rabbitmq.client` text on next line starts from the begginning or have some spaces in front of it?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just do a:

```
grep -A1 ERROR
```

The `-A1` tells grep to include 1 line after the match. `-B` includes lines before the match, in case you need that too.

Comment: oh right, that would be helpful too.

Comment: And `-C` includes lines both before and after the match (the 'C' stands for 'context', I believe).

Comment: I always get this mixed up because I instinctively think these stand for "above" and "below".

Answer (score 7):

For a more portable way, there's awk

```
awk '/ERROR/{n=NR+1} n>=NR' foo.log
```

Or maybe you want all the indented lines following?

```
awk '/^[^[:blank:]]/{p=0} /ERROR/{p=1} p' foo.log
```

Comment: :O that is good information, but rather overkill! nonetheless, its good to know a different method :)

Comment: I wish I understood how those `awk` commands work.

Comment: @Firefeather http://awk.freeshell.org/ is a good resource for learning awk. The GNU awk manual page is pretty good too.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this solution:

```
cat apache.error.log | grep -Pzo '^.*?Exception In get Message.*?\ncom\.rabbitmq.*?(\n(?=\s).*?)*$'
```

Where `(\n(?=\s).*?)*` means:

- `\n` find next line
- `(?=\s)` where is starts from whitespace character
- `.*?` until end of line
- `(...)*` Find such lines multiple times

PS. You may turf this pattern `\ncom\.rabbitmq.*?` if second line begins from whitespace `\s`

Answer (score 2):

For this simple task a simple way is:

```
grep -A num
Print num lines of trailing context after each match. See also the -B and -C options.

grep -B num
Print num lines of leading context before each match. See also the -A and -C options.

grep -C num
Print num lines of leading and trailing context surrounding each match.
The default is 2 and is equivalent to -A 2 -B 2.
```

Note: no whitespace may be given between the option and its argument.