# Grep for a word in a file and show below and above lines too?

Tags: grep, find, top

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to grep 2 or 3 lines, one containing the text I want, and the others just below it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27838/how-to-grep-2-or-3-lines-one-containing-the-text-i-want-and-the-others-just-be)

Say I have a file. I want to find a particular word in that file and show the line.

Is there a way I can do the above, but also include the above and below 10 lines from the result line?

How would I do this using the Linux command line?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your file is called **`filename`**, your regular expression is **`foo`**, and you want to print matching lines and lines within 10 lines (above and below) matching lines:

`grep -C10 foo filename`

More generally, for **`n`** lines before and after matches:

`grep -Cn foo filename`

This solution will work with GNU grep (which Ubuntu and just about every other Linux-based operating system has). The `-C` flag is not necessarily supported in all `grep` implementations, though.

To print lines *only* before or only after matches, use the `-Bn` or `-An` switches respectively, where `n` is the number of lines you want before or after. For more information about an alternative way to do it, see [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27838/how-to-grep-2-or-3-lines-one-containing-the-text-i-want-and-the-others-just-be) (kudos to [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) for noticing the similarity).